# EventListener on TreeNode codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

I would like to create the node listener for the tree component.on clicking the node i would like to display the form related to the node ..
on searching, i found bindNodeListener is available but how to use that method

Answer (score 0):

That method is a callback not a listener. It's meant for people subclassing tree. You can bind to a leaf using a listener you can bind to a node manually and replace the entire functionality of that that node...

```
Form current = new Form("Tree", new BorderLayout());

Tree t = new Tree() {

    @Override
    protected Component createNode(Object node, int depth) {
        Component c = super.createNode(node, depth);
        if(!getModel().isLeaf(node) && c instanceof Button) {
            Button b = (Button)c;
            b.addActionListener(e -> ToastBar.showMessage("You expanded: " + node, FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO));
        }
        return c;
    }

};
current.add(CENTER, t);
t.addLeafListener(e -> ToastBar.showMessage("You clicked: " + e.getSource(), FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO));

current.show();
```

Leaf event looks like this

[image: Leaf event]

Node expansion event looks like this

[image: Node expansion]

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: i need listener on clicking colors node not on leaf

Comment: Edited my answer